# Invalid date when using a unix timestamp with letters in it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

This is the timestamp I have: `5fb6995`

When I do `new Date('5fb6995')` Invalid Date gets returned. But when I try converting it online in an online converter, everything works. Why doesn't this work and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your hexadecimal timestamp to decimal with parseInt and radix 16.

However your timestamp is in hours or something

```js
const ts = parseInt("5fb6995",16); 
console.log(new Date(ts)); // 1970
console.log(new Date(ts*1000)); // still 1973 (Unix TSs are normally in seconds since Epoch - 1970/01/01)

// perhaps you want hh-mm-ss from that UNIX timestamp:

console.log(
  new Date(ts * 1000).toISOString().slice(11,-5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your string `5fb6995` is in hexadecimal base, you need to first convert it to decimal:

```
new Date(parseInt("5fb6995", 16));
```